# Android falls on custom-view basic constructor

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Here is my code when I'm trying to create a custom view. I understand it should define 3 basic constructors to override. I do not understand why it falls on declaration custom view constructors if I add JSONObject. I still override all needed constructors in super. It works fine if I remove JSONObject from all 3 constructors and leave it in default form.

What can be a problem?

```
public abstract class _ASListItem extends ConstraintLayout implements IControl, IASListItem
{
    private JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    public void onSetJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject)
    {
        this.jsonObject = jsonObject;
    }

    public JSONObject onGetJSONObject() { return this.jsonObject; }


    public _ASListItem(JSONObject jsonObject, Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        this.onSetJSONObject(jsonObject);
    }
    public _ASListItem(JSONObject jsonObject, Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context,attrs);
        this.onSetJSONObject(jsonObject);
    }

    public _ASListItem(JSONObject jsonObject, Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context,attrs,defStyle);
        this.onSetJSONObject(jsonObject);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow()
    {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        this.onSetLayoutView(this);

        this.onInitInstance(this);
        this.onHandleInstance(this);
        this.onUpdateInstance(this);
    }
}
```

Here is an Error I get from a java Interpreter

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mobile.application/mobile.application.activity.activityUserInfo}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class mobile.application.custom.customHeadUserInfo

Comment: You can't overload "default" constructors of view with custom params. Just remove `JSONObject` from constructors and use `onSetJSONObject(JSONObject jsonObject)` method

Comment: Thank you. I have also read a lot of info and it must be as you says. In addition, it always runs at least two basic constructors.